# Replaced views in LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="100dp"
          android:background="#535353">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/promo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and I want to replace promo and title. Set first title, then promo.

I use this snippet.

```
public class AdView extends LinearLayout{

TextView promo;


public AdView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view, this);
    promo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.promo);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
}

private void changePosition() {
    removeView(promo);
    addView(promo);
}
```

But, I get error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

So, could you help me? How can I do this?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?
if you want to replace them, why dont you go for reordering them in XML itself?
or please explain your demand in detail.

Comment: I want to create many different views, which based in this layout. All of them have title and promo, but in different position and with different size. So, I want to move and change it position (and size) dynamically in code.

Comment: this is because AdView doesn't have a direct "promo" child,  "promo" is a grand child of AdView

Comment: @pskink, you are right! I have add new parent view (RelativeLayut->LinearLayout->promoView) and change code ViewGroup vg = ((ViewGroup)promo.getParent());
        vg.removeView(promo);
        vg.addView(promo); Now all works fine. Thanks!